# How to set up KeyBindings the reactiveui way?

Tags: c#, wpf, key-bindings, reactiveui

I'd like to know how to set up KeyBindings (Shortcuts) in the reactiveui way. I know about the reactiveui.events package and I'm able to use it for single key events or sequences as described in the handbook. But I'm stuck at using it for something like Ctrl+Up or anything like that.

I tried the handbook k-code example but that is for a sequence of key events and is not working for something like Ctrl+Up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KeyUp` returns an `IObservable<KeyEventArgs>` that you can compose as usual. Try this:

```
this.Events().KeyUp
    .Where(x => x.Key == Key.Up && (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)))
    .Subscribe(_ => MessageBox.Show("CTRL+Up detected!"));
```

Comment: Just to let others know... If you don't want the original behavior of a hook, you should set KeyEvent.Handled to true. So the event doesn't get handled in other hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using HasFlag instead of looking for both Left and Right control click

```
this.Events().KeyUp
             .Where(x => x.Key == Key.Up && Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control))
             .Subscribe(_ => MessageBox.Show("CTRL+Up detected!"));
```